# How to write consistent code using Numpy/Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm new to python and numpy/scipy. The design of Numpy array and the broadcasting rule in numpy/scipy is sometime quite helpful while remaining a lot of pain to me.

I read something like

> Numpy tries to keep the array in the lowest dimension.

somewhere.

Here are some situations.

1. I would like to receive a matrix and calculate its eigenvalues and do some stuff. There will be a moment that a 1d array(e.g, array(1.0) - that comes from a result of a numpy operation), namely a scale pass to this function. I need to write something like

   ```
   if (A.ndim < 2):
       A = sp.array([[A]])
   ```

   to prevent `scipy.linalg.eig` showing

   > ValueError: expected square matrix
2. When doing some machine learning problem, I write thing like

   ```
   n_samples, n_features = X.shape if X.ndim > 1 else (1, X.shape[0])
   ```

   I just need to write extra code to gain the number of samples and features and prevent

   > IndexError: tuple index out of range

   Or sometimes I only need the number of features when the row of a matrix represents a sample, and the column of a matrix represents a feature. I need to write something like

   ```
   n_features = X.shape[1] if X.ndim > 2 else X.shape[0]
   ```

   or do some preprocessing like

   ```
   if (X.ndim < 2):
       X = X[np.newaxis, :]
   ```

   to keep things go well.
3. Sometimes I write thing like

   ```
   sp.dot(weight.T, X.T - mu[:, sp.newaxis])
   ```

   Everything seems fine until I find that `mu` will possibly be a 1d array or a int scaler ! Then the exception

   > TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
   >   or
   >
   > IndexError: too many indices for array

almost make me crazy.

There are even more  cases like this ... All of this seems come from the rule mentioned as the fisrt quote, e.g, when I am expecting a matrix even a 1x1 one, numpy tries to reduce it into a 0-dim array(namely, array(1.0)).

I'm used to be a matlab user and now get into Numpy/Scipy. Beyond the simple and math-friendly matlab syntax, there still less pain in matlab.

I read some code in the source of sklearn package, there also be lots of code worrying 'is this thing a vector or matrix ?', 'shall we add a new axis to it?'.

What is the best way to reduce the pain of writing this ?

Comment: This question is not related to MATLAB. I'm going to remove the tag.

Comment: Can somebody tell me why down voting this question ?

Comment: It wasn't me. I just removed the [matlab] tag as irrelevant.

Comment: @CST-Link I know it, I am just looking for a place to shout ...

Answer (score 2):

`np.atleast_2d` might solve all your issues.

Even the last might be written as:

```
np.dot(weight.T, (X - np.atleast_2d(mu)).T)
```

or maybe

```
np.dot(X-np.atleast_2d(mu), weight)  # tested with (3,2),(2,3) arrays
```

---

The issue of matlab/numpy compatibility has been around for a long time.  There's at least one documentation page devoted to the topic.

There's an `ndarray` subclass that ensures everything it touches is a 2d matrix.  That was true of MATLAB when I started to use it.  It was a big deal when the allowed 3d and higher.  But experienced `numpy` users discourage its use.  There are SO questions in which the poster got messed up by `np.matrix`.

I learned early on in MATLAB that keeping dimensions straight was the biggest part of debugging.  I got in the habit of defining test matrices with shapes that helped identify mismatches (and the need for actions like transpose).  The same applies in `numpy`.

MATLAB users are always wondering, 'is this a column vector or a row vector?', and throwing `x.'` expressions around.  `numpy` gives you a third choice - a 1d vector.

There have been lots of questions about ensuring an array has `n` dimensions.  Look up the `np.atleast_xxx` functions.  Look for `...[None,:]` syntax.  For `reshape(n,1)` and `reshape(...-1)`.  Functions like `np.sum` accept a `keepdims` parameter.

---

The code for `np.atleast_2d` is:

```
def atleast_2d(*arys):
    res = []
    for ary in arys:
        ary = asanyarray(ary)
        if len(ary.shape) == 0 :
            result = ary.reshape(1, 1)
        elif len(ary.shape) == 1 :
            result = ary[newaxis,:]
        else :
            result = ary
        res.append(result)
    if len(res) == 1:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return res
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It seems that `np.matrix` is not recommended after I read some articles. Maybe `np.atlest_2d` is the unavoidable compromise :)